# How git stores snapshot

Tags: git

Git, as it is said, doesn't store `deltas` but `snapshots`.
Now I have a very precise question.

Let's say I have following code and commit it in `master`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void swap(char *A, int i, int j) {
  int t = A[i];
  A[i] = A[j];
  A[j] = t;
}
void reverse(char *A, int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i++)
    swap(A,i,size-1-i);
}
int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  char A[n];
  int k; 
  cin >> k;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> A[i];
  reverse(A,n-k);
  reverse(A+n-k,k);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << A[i];
  cout << endl;
}
```

and then I change it at only one extra line and add one more `reverse` call in the last fourth line

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void swap(char *A, int i, int j) {
  int t = A[i];
  A[i] = A[j];
  A[j] = t;
}
void reverse(char *A, int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i++)
    swap(A,i,size-1-i);
}
int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  char A[n];
  int k; 
  cin >> k;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> A[i];
  reverse(A,n-k);
  reverse(A+n-k,k);
  reverse(A,n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << A[i];
  cout << endl;
}
```

and then I commit it in the same branch (`master`).

Now my question is what does git store actually. Don't answer me `snapshot`. I want to know what `snapshot` means technically. Does it mean it stores the whole file as it is. This would be really inefficient. Or it actually stores deltas. But if so, then why does it call them snapshots.

Comment: It *will* involve jargon since you are asking about internal storage mechanisms. You should do your homework on read up on the data structures that git uses. [This](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) is as good a reference as any.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim I have already read that. By jargon, I mean don't use the word `snapshot` which doesn't mean anything technically. I understand the different type of Git objects: blob, tree, commit...

Comment: It does have a precise meaning which is a copy of entire directory tree at that point in time. This is exactly what git stores.

Comment: The entire directory at that time includes the file containing the source code in my question. Now how does it store _this_ file? By taking delta or in complete?

Comment: Yes it does. That's what a blob is.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim In that case, I ask something in my question which I would like to get answered, like isn't it inefficient.

Comment: Depends on what you're optimising for. Git sacrifices disk for speed and from that point of view, it's very efficient.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52093/discussion-between-kamalbanga-and-noufal-ibrahim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git will create a new `blob` for the modified file and then a new `tree` for the modified directory and then a new `commit` and then put these three (and other objects that might have been created) into the object database.

The blob for the file is a binary object that contains the object type (blob), the object size and the actual contents. So, yes, if you modify just a single line in a file, git will store the entire thing twice and not just the diff.

In general, git sacrifices disk for speed and from that perspective, it is not, by any means, "inefficient".

This method of storage (called loose objects) is, however, not optimal especially for transport. Hence, git has the ability to pack these loose objects into a pack file and and an index. The packing process will identify objects with small differences, put them together and delta compress them into a pack file. These will be more compact and more efficient from a transport point of view.

This is best I can do with how your question is worded. The link I pointed to in the comments describes what happens when you store something in detail. If you have specific questions, please ask more precisely.

Comment: Thanks. It answers my question. However, the word `snapshot` still confuses me. If all git does is store the whole file in a blob without doing any kind of space optimization then tutorials can say `it stores complete file` rather than saying `it stores snapshots` as if trying to make it look magical.

Comment: It doesn't just store the complete file. It doesn't work at file level. It stores a snapshot of the entire directory tree at the time you committed. I'm sure what you took away from that link I posted but it describes this rather well.

Comment: Let's assume I have a project which has only one source file of 10 KB.  Then I modify one line and commit it and now I have this file which is again 10 KB. So this file is stored by git twice, right? Because I committed it two times after changing one line.

Comment: Also I know it doesn't work at the file level. It stores the content of the file called `blob`. But I guess you understand my query.

Comment: Why are you repeating your question? Yes is it.